# Prevent a paticular JS execution using IE developer tool

Tags: javascript, ie-developer-tools

I have a web page which references a lot of JS file. There is one JS file in which the code is throwing unhandled exception and because of this other functionality not working.

So is there any way in IE developer tool to prevent that script from execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to comment out the offending code.

If that is not an option, you can:

1. Set a breakpoint on the code that is throwing the error
2. When the breakpoint is hit, right-click on the next error-free line.
3. Select "Set Next Statement"
4. Continue Execution (F5)

If you have any feedback on the F12 tools, Let us know!

You can suggest changes and vote on suggestions here: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-internet-explorer-platform/category/84475-f12-developer-tools

Comment: Thanks for quickfix. As this is happening in prod so can't make changes.